# How to write and use a converter (pattern)

Tags: java, server, converters

I am developing a map on the client side. In order to pass this generated map to the Server I need to convert my objects (Map and and MapGeneration) I already have a suggestion below, but it is not entirely clear to me how to continue using the converter.

**Server Classes:**

```
public final class EMap{

 private final int x;
 private final int y;
 private final boolean present;
 private final ETerrain terrain; // (Enum: Grass, Water, Mount)

 public EMap() {
    ....
 }

 public EMap(int x, int y, boolean present, ETerrain terrain) {
    ......
 }

}

public class EMapGeneration{

    private final Set<EMap> nodes = new HashSet<>();

    public EMapGeneration(){
    super();
    }

    public EMapGeneration(String id, Collection<EMap> nodes){
     ......
    }

}
```

**Client Classes:**

```
public class Map{
 private Coordinates coordinates; // int x; int y;
 private Area area; // Terrain terrain; (Enum: Grass, Water, Mount), boolean present;
}


public class MapGeneration{
 private List<Map> listMap = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

**My Approch:**

```
public class Converter{

    public EMap converter (Map map){
        EMap eMap = new Emap();

        //how to convert the object to the other object?

    }

    public EMapGeneration converter (MapGeneration mapGeneration){
        EMapGeneration emapGeneration = new EMapGeneration();

      //how to convert the object to the other object?
    }
```

Comment: by ... passing values you get from getters into setters?

Comment: The Server Classes don't have any setters only getters

Comment: so? they have constructors, no? add getters to your client classes, and pass the results of the getters to the constructors

Comment: How i should pass for example my Class Coordinates when it expects two integers?

Comment: your Coordinates class, according to your comments, exists out of two integers. I would assume that somewhat explains that?

Comment: Converters don't work using passing getters as far as I know. I want to convert an object to an another one. That is what i am asking for. Not how to pass getters...

Comment: in that case, you don't understand converters. Converters DO use getters, how else do you think they get that information? it's a re-usable way so you won't have to use the getters elsewhere in your code.
This might give you an idea: https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/converter/

Comment: ah okay, now i understand. Thank you for the link. its very useful

Comment: converters are easy, they don't really do much difficult technic underlying stuff, but they allow you to turn one type into another without having to repeat the entire 'stripping ints from Coordinates' over and over, it's more about convenience. Creating them can save you a lot of work later on, if you need to convert those types often

Comment: I have one question. What if the constructur expects the Class "Eterrain"? He would not accept my "Terrain"? Also, when i use getter

Comment: I know nothing of the class Eterrain, but chances are, you can build that the same way you can build a Coordinate with two ints